# use mysql from dual boot

Tags: mysql, database

I have dual boot on my computer:server2003 and windows7 x64. I used to have mysql run on my server2003, now I want to use my data on windows7 so I installed mysql on windows7 and copy my data dir from g:\data to e:\data, and set datadir to the directory where my database and tables are(E:\data) in my.ini file. The versions of 2 mysql are both 5.5, but not same.

When I started mysql, it took about 2 minutes to start successfully, and when I run "select count(*) from table_c", it took 3 seconds. (there are 500,000 rows in table_c), I think on my server2003, it may take only 1 second. I found the following error records in mycomputername.err file in my data directory,

170629  8:08:11  InnoDB: Error: page 1985 log sequence number 364480492602
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 8214.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.

a lot of these kind of errors with different page numbers.

Did I do anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the following steps. BACK UP YOUR DATA FIRST!!

1) stop the running mysqld service: sudo service mysqld stop

2) export out all databases from mysql : 
   mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > all-databases.sql

3) backup the db files in case you need them:

mv ib_logfile0 ib_logfile0.bak

mv ib_logfile1 ib_logfile1.bak

mv ibdata1 ibdata1.bak

4) restart mysqld service with this flag set: “innodb_force_recovery=4” in my.cnf.
   sudo service mysqld start

5) bring all of your databases back in: mysql -u root -p < all-databases.sql

6) finally restart the mysqld service again with “innodb_force_recovery=4”: sudo service mysqld restart

The export and import steps may take a while if your databases are large so be patient. There are other ways to backup and re-import them that maybe faster.

Good luck.